# Get IBM MQ connection factory in my spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm getting the following error while trying to send a message to an IBM MQ, I created a queue connection factory on Websphere which is tested and successfully connected to the deployed MQs, then I look up over it by jndi name.

I'm using ibm.mq.allclient as a Gradle dependency.

I would appreciate any help.

```
    org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
    The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
    See the linked exception for further information.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0]
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:316)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:169)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:487)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:570)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1232)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:781)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3928)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
    The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
    See the linked exception for further information.
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:314)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:228)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:175)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6200)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:102)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:364)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:98)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.createConnection(JMSManagedConnection.java:1499)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnection.<init>(JMSManagedConnection.java:352)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createUnifiedManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:1301)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(JMSManagedConnectionFactory.java:682)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(WMQJMSRAManagedConnectionFactory.java:704)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2161)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1839)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3818)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3094)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactoryHandle.java:256)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:474)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  ... 75 more
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2195;AMQ9546: Error return code received. [1=java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException[null],3=NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0]
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:987)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:832)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:655)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:167)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  ... 93 more
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.processESESecurity(JmqiEnvironment.java:906)
    [1/6/19 19:32:45:710 EET] 00000245 SystemErr     R  ... 96 more
```

Comment: Do you have a Oracle jms.jar in the classpath? If not add the jms.jar 2.0 from the IBM provider mq client install, either full client,  redist client,  or java-all client.   If you do have a Oracle jms.jar check the manifest.mf to make sure it is the 2.0 version.  Also check that you do not have other com.ibm.mq*.jar files besides the allclient. 2195 is a very generic error that just means unexpected error,  but in many cases it means you have mixed jars from different mq client versions.

Comment: Did you find the problem based on my comment?  If so please let me know so I can write up that part as an answer.

Comment: Indeed the problem was related to ibm.mq jar files. I removed every jar file including allclient jars from my classpath. then I added the jars of the installed IBM mq client in WebSphere. I found these jars under  `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\installedConnectors`, there was a folder called `wmq.jmsra` . and It worked. thank you so much for your help

Comment: If i just finish my comment as an answer will you accept?

Comment: yes, sure your answer put me in the right direction, in the beginning, I thought I should get the path of the native mqjbnd library and add it while creating the connection factory, I didn't think it would be mixed jars problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2195 is a very generic error that just means unexpected error, but in many cases it means you have mixed jars from different mq client versions.  Check the following items:

1. If you do not have an Oracle `jms.jar` in the `CLASSPATH`, add the `jms.jar` 2.0 from the IBM provided MQ client install (This can be from any of the full client, redist client, or java-all client).
2. If you do have an Oracle `jms.jar` check the `MANIFEST.MF` to make sure it is the 2.0 version.
3. Ensure that you do not have other `com.ibm.mq*.jar` files besides the `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`.